# Url rewrite of dynamic php page not working in both directions

Tags: php, url, dynamic, url-rewriting

My web page is largely dynamic. I figured out how to rewrite these URLs  (apache server).

The first page I did is https://www.roguefab.com/category.php?category=Tubing_Benders

The clean URL for this page is https://www.roguefab.com/category/tubing_benders

If you navigate to www.roguefab.com/category/Tubing_Benders, it works perfect (shows my content and the clean URL). If I navigate directly or with a link to the dirty URL, it shows the dirty URL. Why? Shouldn't it show the clean one?

My rewrite code is just like every other one I've seen:
     RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+) category.php?category=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: 2 negative votes and no comments? What is wrong with my qusstion?

Comment: Beats me. Looks fine for me, have an upvote. Wouldn't you want to include the `R` option in your `RewriteRule`? See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html (Edit: however, you improved your questions with your edits, the first version was less clear, hence the downvotes, probably).

Comment: the rewriterule you posted is `path'd -> param'd` (no redirect, which is fine) where/how is the `param'd -> path'd` (dirty -> clean) redirect ?

Comment: if you have the authority for the codebase I would also suggest doing this via a routing lib (i.e. [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)) - way less hassle, since you dont have to fiddle with apache, and get-params

Comment: I agree with you birdspider, but then it would be a circular argument, wouldn't it? And I have looked at tons of these and never seen one with a redirect required. Are all the tutorials and examples wrong or incomplete?

Comment: How should the browser change the URL entered to something else without a redirect in the RewriteRule? The rewrite happens on the server side and basically just tells the server "if this URL is called, fetch the content from there". The client doesn't know any of this, so how should it change its URL?

Comment: @RogueFabrication, no circular argument: in case 1 it's "clean" you just extract the params, case 2 "dirty" gets redirected to "clean" version